# HTML5 drag& drop is throwing undefined is not a function error

Tags: javascript, html

I am new in HTML5 & trying to learn drag & drop feature.I have a JavaScript function for creating div element & attaching dragstart event to it.

```
var taskDefination = document.createElement("div");
        taskDefination.className = "defaultButtonHolder";
        taskDefination.setAttribute("draggable","true");
        document.getElementById("toDo").getElementsByClassName('columnContent')[0].appendChild(taskDefination);
        taskDefination.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
}
```

Now I have a drop zone created as

```
<span class="columnWidth">
                <div class ="columnHeader">Progress</div>
                <div class ="columnContent" ondragenter ="dragDrop.dragEnter(event)"></div>
            </span>
```

where the dragEnter function belongs to an external javascript file where it has been designed as a closure.I have checked network tab and this javascript file is perfectly loading.

```
var dragDrop = function(){
    var _dragEnter = function(){
        console.log("Dragged dropped");
        }   
    return{
        dragEnter:_dragEnter
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is whenever i am trying to drop the element in dropzone it is throwing an undefined not a function error. But ondropeneter event , if calling a function written in same HTML page  it is perfectly executing.Why does it throwing an undefined not an function error though it is working fine function written in same HTML page?

Comment: *"designed as a closure"* so is it wrapped into some other function?

Comment: yes it is wrapped inside dragDrop function.

Comment: Debug your code I'm on my phone but I believe your dragDrop code has a few erroneous logics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closure isn't properly formed. As it stands, `dragDrop` is a function object returned from the function expression and as such doesn't have the code you want attached to it. Have a quick read of function expressions here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

It looks like you're trying to use a closure to implement a module pattern. To do this, you need to rebuild your code like this:

```
var dragDrop = (function() {
    var _dragEnter = function(){
        console.log("Dragged dropped");
    }   
    return {
        dragEnter:_dragEnter
    }
})();
```

The first set of brackets around the `(function {})` make it a closure. The second set of brackets afterwards `(function {})()` execute it immediately. This means your module is returned to the `var dragDrop` and then you will be able to successfully call `dragDrop.dragEnter`.

Comment: Absolutely right. I am implementing revealing module pattern & this soln worked. Thanks for the link